# Firebase combined Observables in Ionic 2/Angular 2 Project - They only update once

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 project where I'm using Firebase and I've been trying to master the art of creating many-to-many relationships, utilizing observables. In some of my previous questions, I've been making some progress where I can aggregate separate paths into one observable.

However, using my latest code, it would seem that when I update the data in the Firebase database, it only updates the observable a single time. After that, the UI doesn't update and I have to refresh the page in order to pull the latest data from the Firebase database.

Here is my function:

```
public getUserProfile(data) {
    return this._af.database
      .object(`/social/users/${data.id}`)

      // Switch to the joined observable

      .switchMap((user) => {

        let vidKeys = Object.keys(user.videos);


        return Observable.combineLatest(
          vidKeys.map((vidKey) => this._af.database
            .object(`/social/videos/${vidKey}`)
          ),
          (...videos) => {
            vidKeys.forEach((vidKey, index) => { user.videos[vidKey] = videos[index] });
            return user;
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

Update: Adding the code that calls this function.

In my component:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    this._users.getUserProfile({id: 'c25zdGFyb3NjJJuYtREaYWlsLmNvbQ=='}).subscribe(success => {
      this.user = success;

      this.videoKeys = Object.keys(this.user.videos);
    });

  }
```

In my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of videoKeys">
        {{user.videos[key].title}}
        <img src="{{user.videos[key].thumbnail}}" />
      </div>
```

Here is what my database object for my user looks like:

```
{
    users: {
     c25zdGFyb3NjJJuYtREaYWlsLmNvbQ==
       videos {
         AFA-rOls8YA: true,
         AlLsp4gnyDQ: true,
         dX_1B0w7Hzc: true,
         ik5qR5bw75E: true,
         njos57IJf-0: true
       },
       videos {
         AFA-rOls8YA {
           attached_members {
             c25zdGFyb3NjJJuYtREaYWlsLmNvbQ==: true
           }
           title: "Hello...it's me"
         },
         AlLsp4gnyDQ: { ... },
         dX_1B0w7Hzc: { ... },
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This question is an extension of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597665/angularfire2-nested-firebaseobjectobservable-wont-fire-a-nested-firebase-call/40598139?noredirect=1#comment68438146_40598139).

I'm still relatively new to observables, but does anyone think they have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Could you include some of the code that calls and consumes the observable returned by `getUserProfile`? Can you confirm that you don't use `first` or `take(1)` on the returned observable?

Comment: Alright, I realized I need to show the template as well. I'm not sure if how I'm rendering the observable subscribe results, but I had to do it the way I'm doing it in my code. Could that be having an effect? It's all there now

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realized after some trial and error that there was nothing wrong with the code that is posted or from my previous answer. There was an error in my code that I wasn't picking up during my tests. I commented the problem code and the updates are happening consistently, as expected.

Let this be a lesson where you quadruple check code you had expected to work since it was working before.